# What happen if I try to get sizeof an undefined variable? (PHP)

Tags: php, native-methods

(PHP)
What happen if I try to get an undefined variable size with sizeof method?

Like:

```
<?
print_r(sizeof($undefined_variable));
```

Can I do this?
What's the value?

In my playground always run into error, but when i try this code:

```
<?
print_r(sizeof($undefined_variable));
exit();
```

[image: Size of an undefined variable picture]

I'm so curious after error why I get back a zero value. Sorry for my bad English

Comment: What if use this in a foor loop like this: `for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($undefined_variable); $i++) {...}` Is it working?

Comment: Is this a serious question or are you just taking the micky. As you can see from your output. **You get an Warning message**

Comment: PS: `print_r()` is a function for showing the contents of an array, not a scaler variable

Comment: The `0` is returned to stop PHP falling of its purch laughing

Comment: Please read the basic syntax and come. :) :) :) p)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`sizeof` is an exact alias of `count`. `count()` can only return the number of items in an object if the object interfaces with the `Countable` interface which an undefined variable does not which is causing the error.

However the reason for the 0 being output is that print_r outputs a 0 anytime an error has occured.

for example try:

```
print_r(4 + hello);
```

It still outputs a 0. The error was non fatal so the program continues to execute.

To answer your second question, if you try the following code:

```
for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($undefined_variable); $i++) {
    echo $i;
}

echo "Hi";
```

Only 'Hi' will get output. The error aborts the whole for loop.

Comment: Do you have any idea, how it's work in a for loop? If I hide the errors and write something like this: `for ($i=0; $i<=sizeof($undefined_variable); $i++) {...}` could be overcharge the server?

Comment: @GáborEndreSzabó the for loop won't run at all.

Comment: Between in PHP 7.0
`print_r(4 + hello)` output: 4
`print_r(4 + "hello")` output: 4
`print_r(4 + $hello)` output still 4

Comment: @GáborEndreSzabó really? I must have tried it in a different version. PHP 7 is probably trying to salvage what it can from the error and just ignoring the `+ hello`. `hello + hello` would probably still create an error though.

Comment: @Progrock Its essentially an error though, its just a non-fatal one which PHP calls a notice.

Comment: `print_r(4+'hello')` and `print_r(hello)`, outputs `4` and `hello` respectively for me, even though the latter triggers a notice. (Php 5.6).

Comment: @Progrock hmmm very strange, I didn't know PHP was so robust.

Comment: Please add your Php version.

Comment: I can't get print_r to output 0.  And the notice doesn't abort the loop, rather the conditional becomes 0<0, which evaluates to false. See: https://3v4l.org/M8rGm, https://3v4l.org/CHLbI

Answer (score -1):

sizeof() is an array funciton returns the size of the array,
so you will get php warning about variable( not decalred) and also
a 0 as result.

Comment: From the manual, count(): Returns the number of elements in array_or_countable. If the parameter is not an array or not an object with implemented Countable interface, 1 will be returned. There is one exception, if array_or_countable is NULL, 0 will be returned.

Comment: sorry it was typing mistake , check now

Comment: Count returning a 0 for an uncountable isn't particularly intuitive. That's why there is a cautionary note in the manual.

Answer (score -1):

From the manual for the function - count():

> Caution count() may return 0 for a variable that isn't set, but it may
>   also return 0 for a variable that has been initialized with an empty
>   array. Use isset() to test if a variable is set.

sizeof is an alias of count.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php

Hence:

```
<?php
print_r(sizeof($undefined_variable));
```

Will output:

```
0
```

As `sizeof($undefined_variable)` evaluates to `0`, and `print_r(0)` results in `0`.